# question about convergence series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm not sure I understand why $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(4pq)^n<\infty $$ when $$p\ne0.5 , p+q=1$$

I know that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=\infty$
But why when we have $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ multiple a number that is smaller than 1, we get a  convergence series?

Comment: which convergence tests have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $4 p q < 1$ (Why?). Let $4 pq = a < 1$. We then have
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{a^k}{\sqrt{k}} < \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a^k = \dfrac{a}{1-a} < \infty$$
The series you have is the [polylogarithm function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm), $\text{Li}_{1/2}(a)$.

Comment: @coward: Down voting without leaving a comment serves no useful purpose.

Comment: I upvoted your answer and think it is a very good answer.